# How to search for multiple conditions in python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a helper script for DnD needs, part of the script should accept either integers or dice notation. The latter is in the format of

```
1d20+4
```

where I can replace `1`, `20` with and natural number, and `+4` with any integer. The input can look like

```
hit +3 damage 1d8+1 hp 3d6+2
```

And I split it into two list using `re`. The problem is that when I try to detect both dies and numbers. I know that that to detect a number I need to use

```
re.listall('[\+\-][0-9]*',input_line)
```

and to detect a die I need to search for

```
re.listall('[0-9]*d[0-9]*',input_line)
```

And I'm quite certain that to search for a die with a bonus I need

```
re.listall('[0-9]*d[0-9]*[\+\-][0-9]*',input_line)
```

However, I can't figure how to search for a combination of the two. I though about placing them in parenthesis, i.e.

```
re.listall('([\+\-][0-9]*)([0-9]*d[0-9]*)',input_line)
```

However, I get an error `sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis`

which leaves me confused. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you need is this regular expression:

```
re.findall('((\d+d\d+)?[\+-]\d+)', input_line)
```

As a side note, you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`. So, the second part is the same as in your code. The first part `'(\d+d\d+)?'` is optional (because of `?`) and matches number followed by the letter d followed by a number.

In your example (`hit +3 damage 1d8+1 hp 3d6+2`), this will match `+3`, `1d8+1` and `3d6+2`

Comment: Thank you, how can I give the option of two digit number? e.g. ``hit +12``

Comment: The regex I gave you should already be doing it ... `\d+` means 1 or more of [0-9] digits. so it should be matching an optional sequence of [1 or more digits]d[1or more digits], then it matches a + or - sign and then [1 or more digits]

Answer (score 1):

You can use to following regex with `re.findall()`,*Note* that as certainly you have a number in your pattern you can put `\d{1,}` within combinations of word characters and `+-` :

```
>>> s ='hit +3 damage 1d8+1 hp 3d6+2'
>>> re.findall(r'([\S+-]*\d{1,}[\S+-]*)+',s)
['+3', '1d8+1', '3d6+2']
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/PCaJfiWHUKOm_OEE)

Comment: Thanks. How can I handle multi digit numbers? e.g. ``hit +12``